# Reconnect VGA cable doesnt give signal until reboot

Tags: vga, displayport, display-adapter

My equip is connected to a VGA monitor through a DisplayPort To VGA adapter.
When the computer is powered on with this adapter connected, the monitor outputs a video signal as expected.

However, if I unplug either the adapter or monitor and reconnect them, the monitor loses signal. This happens with multiple monitors until I restart the computer.

This happens while booted in Linux, Windows and even in the BIOS. This does not occur if I use an HDMI to VGA adapter.